# Viewing media files directly in FireFox

Tags: firefox, vlc-media-player

I'm looking for a way to view ALL the video file extensions in firefox. For example: avi, 
f4v, flv, mpg, mp4. 
The idea is to prevent the file to be opened by an external application (VLC, in my case) and view it in plain HTML page.

Using Windows 7 and Firefox 3.6.8.

I found [jwplayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) but it supports only a limited number of extensions.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean you want all those formats played by a player embedded into the web page?  FF through version 3 doesn't play any video files directly, it uses plugins.

The mplayer plugin can do this on Linux.  To give a more complete answer we would need to know what version of Firefox you're using on what operating system.  Be specific, say "Debian GNU/Linux 4.0" instead of "Linux" please.